# Fetching DB2 data from IBM i using Java

Tags: java, db2

I need to fetch DB2 data from user libraries on an IBM i machine using Java. I'm using JTOpen400. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to rephrase your question. RPGLE files does not exist on an iSeries. Everything is a DB2 table (which can be used with RPGLE offcourse).

If you have JTOpen400, then I advice to use JDBC. With JDBC the iSeries is a regular DB2 database server. It works like any other database server. Just follow the JDBC guidelines as describes in many books, manuals and websites.

Answer (score 0):

Check SequentialFile for this.  Remember to set the record format, and then you can pick out the fields for each line as you iterate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDBC (driver provided by JT400) to access DB2/400 files on the iSeries just like any other database.

The JDBC URL would be something like `jdbc:as400://system-name/default-schema;properties`

See http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400JDBCDriver.html for more information.